# How make jquery menuAim dropdown fixed?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

How to keep the jquery menuAim dropdown fixed at the same place like this:

https://www.iherb.com

i've tried this code below but the dropdown shows below of each li.

instead of use rowSelector should a toogle the div?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#main-nav").menuAim({
    rowSelector: "li.parentnav",
    submenuDirection: "below",

    tolerance: 0,
    exitMenu: function(){return true;},
    activate: function(a){
        $(a).children('.subnav').show();
    },
    deactivate: function(a){
        $(a).children('.subnav').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Please guide me how to do this those who knows?

Comment: Make the question more understandable so that the readers can contribute.

Comment: @YashParekh, thank you i edited the question

Comment: what about CSS you can easily do it with CSS. mentions your website link. or CSS code

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj, sorry i did not understand what you mean

Comment: did you try to adjust it with css? also have you working link?

Comment: this is just ajustable by js and the working link exemple:

Comment: http://www.netshoes.com.br